# Price Not Displaying On Individual Product Page Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

http://iheartdecor.co.uk/product/burlap-coffee-sack-cushions/

I have entered the price 30.00 which displays in the gallery http://iheartdecor.co.uk/product-category/cushions/

But when I go onto the product itself (individual product page) It doesn't display the price?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Price is displayed, but in a white color, check the CSS .price class and change the color value.